# C lib calling on global variable in another lib

Tags: c, global-variables

I have two libraries, to simplify:
libA.lib, libB.lib

libA has function:

```
void read(num,*val){
*val=Globalval[num];
...
}
```

libB:

```
void write(num,val){
Globalval[num]=val;
...
}
```

that is the gist of what I want to achieve. The two libs are included in my main project files and the functions are called individually. So how do I have this work out? If the two libs were of the same lib, a simply global variable would be all I need.

I'm using microsoft visual studios

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  This scenario works - you can declare global variables in a shared header file, define them in one lib, and use them from anything staticly linked in.

Comment: How about the more obvious statement that this is bad library design?

Comment: @asveikau I'm not doing exactly what is stated, just trying to figure out how to call variables from other libs. If the act of doing such is called bad design, then why would such functions be allowed? Please comment if you have more constructive criticisms.

Comment: A language allows you to do all sorts of bad designs.  This should not be taken as an endorsement.  The drawbacks of globals are well documented.

Comment: I'm well aware the inefficiencies of globals, but there are instances where there are no alternatives. Otherwise, why would globals be part of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the files, probably the write one (libB), put something like this:

```
int Globalval[SIZE];
```

In its header file, which should be included by libA, put this:

```
extern int Globalval[];
```

If your example really is what you're doing though, keep both functions in the same file, and call them from wherever you need to. In that case, you just put the function prototypes in the header.

Comment: yea i'm not going for exactly read and write, this is simply the easiest way to get my point across.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use EXTERN

in one of your libs header file:

```
extern int g_myGlobal;
```

in one of your libs cpp file:

```
int g_myGlobal;
```

You would then have to include the header file from one lib in the other (or any other file) that wants to use g_myGlobal

Comment: I've tried this method before however the global value never updated from write to read. I had a common header file with the extern declaration, and in write i set it to 1. However in my read functions, when I call for it, the value I get back is 0, the default

Comment: Perhaps it is a threading / syncronization issue, try prepending the definition with "volatile"

Comment: just to be clear on if I'm setting things up right. I have a global.h file with the extern declaration. This is included in both libs. In libB, the source has the int g_myGlobal definition. In libA I also have to define g_myGlobal as int. LibB's function sets g_myGlobal=1 and libA's function printfs it. From this I get 0 for the global. I'll try volatile though

Comment: no, you do NOT define it in libA, you use the libB's header file (which has the EXTERN) in in your LibA's cpp file.

Comment: @mugetsu: Are you sure you `#include "global.h"` in libA? You shouldn't define `g_myGlobal` as int in it. Perhaps you have a linker problem.

Comment: but i had to that, otherwise I get the undefined symbol error. In libA I have the header file, but thats just a declaration, the file needs a definition as well.

Comment: @nmichaels yep I did do the include, you might be right about the linker issue. How can I further troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: @mugetsu: You've moved from C to Microsoft's linker. I can't help you there.